# Sony Viao Model PCG-71311L Possible Drivers Issue-High Cpu Usage at Idle

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, drivers, sony-vaio

I had this old laptop laying around and I am trying to fix it. It needed a battery and an new drive. I already installed an ssd in it and got windows 10 installed on it. I am currently waiting on a battery to arrive, so in the mean time I have been just having the laptop connected to the charger.

Anyways, when i looked into device manager it had 2 devices with check marks so signify that drivers are not installed. I noticed this because the original problem after I installed windows 10 was the cpu percentage was ramping up to like 90-100% when I was doing basically nothing on idle. This is a new install fresh clean of windows 10, so no viruses. I got rid of 1 of the device driver checker as I took the hard ware ID and found it. However, the other one has a driver ID of PCI\VEN_1180&DEV_E230&SUBSYS_9071104D&REV_00. When I put this into google it brings up that the id is the pcie memory stick host controller driver. I downloaded it and installed the driver. However, it still shows up as missing in device manager and the laptop is still running extremely high cpu usage when it shouldn't be even though it is an old cpu. I tried installing the driver twice to no avail. All windows 10 updates are installed.

I can fell the laptop is hot, due to it ramping up as high cpu usage. I did install a stick of ram from another laptop and it shows up properly in windows. I am not for sure if this is a hardware issue or a software issue, but the driver I know is correct is not being recognized on the laptop. I know windows 7 drivers are on sony's website for this laptop but that will work on windows 10 as well. Does anyone have any ideas of why the driver won't be recognized or what the issue is?

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions as to what is causing high CPU usage. Have you used Task Manager to find out what is causing it? https://askleo.com/how_do_i_find_out_what_program_is_using_all_my_cpu/

Comment: Yes I used task manager to actually find out that it was high cpu usage and the program I forgot the name but i looked it up and it is a common windows background application that would be using very little resources assuming a perfectly find running machine. So something is wrong and keep in mind it is a fresh install so no viruses if that is what your thinking.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get an answer here, sorry. It's just too vague of a question and it is impossible to troubleshoot with this explanation. If it is a clean install it's either a driver problem or a hardware problem. Update drivers first. If not, it's most likely bad hardware.

Comment: How is this vague? What information would you like? I don't think its hardware it turns on and everything booting into hardware just that driver not installing correctly. Unless I have the wrong driver.